# Trigger to restrict users from creating a new table in the database

Tags: sql-server, trigger, ssms

How do I create a SQL Server trigger that will restrict any users from creating a new table in the database?

Please help me with this.

Thanks & Regards,
Ritesh.

Comment: Use permissions to "restrict any user from creating a new table in the database "

Comment: Or more exactly, don't *grant* them the permissions needed to create tables in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really must use a trigger you can use a database trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER NoCreateTable ON DATABASE 
    FOR CREATE_TABLE
AS 
PRINT 'You may not create a table' 
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you will still have created the table. Its just that it gets rolled back. A small difference,but it may be important to you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but we had a similar scenario where we granted developers control database rights, but we wanted to block them from managing tables. So I came up with this server trigger. Posting for anyone in the future who comes to this post:

```
USE [master]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


/***
Create Date: 2017-03-01
Author: Tim Cartwright
Description: |-
    Block users from being able to alter tables or w/e else as we grant them control rights.
    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510452.aspx DDL Event Groups
Revisions:
  - Revision Date: 2019-04-23
    Author: Matthew Naul    
    Description: added handling for DDL Admin role  
***/
ALTER TRIGGER [block_user_modifications]
    ON ALL SERVER 
    FOR DDL_TABLE_EVENTS
    AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @data XML  
    SET @data = EVENTDATA() 

    DECLARE @DbName nvarchar(128) = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)[1]', 'nvarchar(128)')

    -- ignore any databases that you allow them to play in
    IF @DbName = 'PlayGround' RETURN;
    
    -- seperated the rights out into seperate output parameters just in case we wish to do something different with them.
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX) = 'USE [' + @DbName + ']; SELECT @db_owner = IS_ROLEMEMBER (''db_owner''), @db_ddladmin = IS_ROLEMEMBER (''db_ddladmin'')',
        @db_owner int, @db_ddladmin int;

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @stmt=@sql, @params = N'@db_owner int output, @db_ddladmin int output', @db_owner = @db_owner OUTPUT, @db_ddladmin = @db_ddladmin OUTPUT
    
    IF (IS_SRVROLEMEMBER('sysadmin') + @db_owner + @db_ddladmin) = 0 BEGIN

        -- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187909.aspx Use the EVENTDATA Function
        DECLARE @action varchar(50), 
            @schema_name nvarchar(255),
            @object_name nvarchar(255)

        SELECT @action = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
            @schema_name = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]',  'NVARCHAR(255)'),
            @object_name = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]',  'NVARCHAR(255)');

        DECLARE @ErrorMsg varchar(1024) = 'User (' + SUSER_NAME() + ') does not have the appropriate rights to perform the ' + @action 
            + ' action on object ' + @DbName + '.' + @schema_name + '.' + @object_name + '. Please contact your DBA.';

        ROLLBACK;
        RAISERROR ( 'DDL Trigger: %s', 18, 1, @ErrorMsg) 
            WITH 
                LOG,        -- Make sure this error is in the SQL Log
                NOWAIT,     -- Return the error now
                SETERROR;   -- Sets @@ERROR and ERROR_NUMBER
    END
END

GO
```